# Recognise click on link within web page in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview, objective-c++

I want to load one URL in web view which is in my application. If user clicks on any URL on that web page then I want to open clicked URL in default safari app i.e. out of my application.
I know     shouldStartLoadWithRequest: but it will get call whenever new URL starts loading even if it is loading an image in my web page.

How can I recognise that user clicked on URL on my web page?

Comment: What kind of images are loaded? I mean is the URL specific, so that you can maybe test for the last URL-component if it has a file-ending like JPG /PNG?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check the `navigationType` parameter in `webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType:`

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView*)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest*)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType { 
  switch (navigationType) {
    case UIWebViewNavigationTypeLinkClicked:
      // user clicked on link
    break;
    case UIWebViewNavigationTypeOther: 
      // request was caused by an image that's being loaded
    break;
  }
  return YES; 
}
```

There are more UIWebViewNavigationTypes that you can use to determine what caused the request:

```
enum {
   UIWebViewNavigationTypeLinkClicked,
   UIWebViewNavigationTypeFormSubmitted,
   UIWebViewNavigationTypeBackForward,
   UIWebViewNavigationTypeReload,
   UIWebViewNavigationTypeFormResubmitted,
   UIWebViewNavigationTypeOther
};
typedef NSUInteger UIWebViewNavigationType;
```